# Build python package wheel on release GitHub event

Tags: python, github-actions

I'm looking for a way to configure GitHub workflow so every time I create new release for my python package with a tag it builds new artefact (python wheel) and adds it to release. Is it possible to do without additional service?

Comment: yes, it is possible, and, in fact, there are many different ways to do this. Please provide more details to make a more informed response. E.g. - where should the wheel go (published to PyPI, added to the release, etc.), is it a manylinux package, does it involve C/C++ code etc. A GitHub link would answer many of these, too

Comment: You might want to check out the [Packaging Guide](https://packaging.python.org/guides/publishing-package-distribution-releases-using-github-actions-ci-cd-workflows/) if you haven't already.

Comment: I don’t want to push it to PyPi server, as this is internal project and I don’t have privacy PyPi server yet. This is why I want sure about Packaging Guide. @Marat it does not have any C++ code, just python. But it should work on Linux and Windows